# How to solve trisecting a pentagon

Tags: equation-solving, graphics, geometry

I thought maybe I could learn Mathematica to help me trisect a pentagon. I can't figure out how to write a `Solve` to get `d0` on `L0` to match all the other `d`'s around it. The slider changes `d` and the three lines stay an equal distance from the edges. I estimated `d0` to be .4935 but I was hoping to get an "exact" answer using `Solve` or something similar. Sorry for the static labels. I'm really just trying to solve for the segment length of `d0` to equal the segment length of `d`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (code updated)

[image: trisect pentagon]

```
p = Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, π/2 + 2 π/5, -3 π/2 + 2 π/5, -2 π/5}]
dp[d_] := d Sin[2 Pi/5] (* d'prime *)
Manipulate[
 i1 = Solve[{x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[1]], p[[5]]}] &&
    {x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[5]] + {0, dp[d] }, p[[4]] + {0, dp[d]}}], {x, y}];
 i2 = Solve[{x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[1]] + {d, 0}, p[[5]] + {d, 0}}] &&
    {x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[5]] + {0, dp[d] }, p[[4]] + {0, dp[d]}}], {x, y}];
 i3 = Solve[{x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[3]] - {d, 0}, p[[4]] - {d, 0}}] &&
    {x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[5]] + {0, dp[d] }, p[[4]] + {0, dp[d]}}], {x, y}];
 i4 = Solve[{x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[3]], p[[4]]}] &&
    {x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[5]] + {0, dp[d] }, p[[4]] + {0, dp[d]}}], {x, y}];
 x0 = Flatten[{x} /. {i1, i2, i3, i4}];

 Graphics[{
   Text[Row[{"d = ", x0[[2]] - x0[[1]], ", d0 = ", x0[[3]] - x0[[2]]}]],
   Text[{"p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"}[[#]], p[[#]] 1.1] & /@ Range[5],
   Line[p], Blue,
   Line[{{0, -0.8}, {0, -0.35}}],
   Text[Subscript["d", "p"], {-.05, -.53}], Black,
   Text[Subscript["d", "0"], {-.05, -.3}],
   Text["d", #] & /@ {
     {-.5, -.3}, {.5, -.3}, {-.63, -.53}, {-.25, -.53},
     {.25, -.53}, {.63, -.53}, {-.35, -.77}, {.35, -.77}
     },
   Text[Subscript["L", "0"], {-1, -.3}],
   Text["i1", {-.7, -.3}], Text["i2", {-.32, -.3}],
   Text["i3", {.32, -.3}], Text["i4", {.7, -.3}],
   InfiniteLine[{p[[1]] + {d, 0}, p[[5]] + {d, 0}}],
   InfiniteLine[{p[[3]] - {d, 0}, p[[4]] - {d, 0}}],
   InfiniteLine[{p[[5]] + {0, dp[d] }, p[[4]] + {0, dp[d]}}]},
  ImageSize -> Automatic],
 {{d, .4935}, .3, .6},
 TrackedSymbols :> d]
```

Comment: I don't see how your approach, even if your technical difficulties were solved, can  divide a regular pentagon into three equal areas

Comment: Your `StringJoin` expression can replaced with the simpler `Row[{"d = ", x0[[2]] - x0[[1]],  ", dp = ", x0[[3]] - x0[[2]],  ", d = ", x0[[4]] - x0[[3]]}]`

Comment: I'm not trying to solve an area, it's a length of `d` problem. I'm trying to find an intersection point `i1` so that the sement length of `i2-i1` equals segment length `i3-i2` equals segment length `i4-i3`. Hope that helps. Sorry I'm not able to explain it very well. Thanks for the tip on `StringJoin`. I'll look at `Row`.

Comment: Here is another tip. `p = Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, π/2 + 2 π/5, -3 π/2 + 2 π/5, -2 π/5}]`

Comment: I love your `Table` function even though I don't understand it yet. I also use `Row` now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit

Maybe this will help you along with your problem. It shows you how to write a `Manipulate` expression that performs as I think you intend. It confirms that `d = .4935` is quite close the trisection point.

In this edit I am adding labels since I found some free time to write the simple—if somewhat tedious—code needed to display them.

```
dp[d_] := d Sin[2. Pi/5]
pts = {"p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"};
p = Table[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} // N, {θ, π/2 + 2 π/5, -3 π/2 + 2 π/5, -2 π/5}];
DynamicModule[{ln1, ln2, ln3, i1, i2, i3, i4},
  Manipulate[
    ln1 = InfiniteLine[{p[[1]] + {d, 0}, p[[5]] + {d, 0}}]; 
    ln2 = InfiniteLine[{p[[3]] - {d, 0}, p[[4]] - {d, 0}}]; 
    ln3 = InfiniteLine[{p[[5]] + {0, dp[d]}, p[[4]] + {0, dp[d]}}];
    i1 =
      Solve[{x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[1]], p[[5]]}] && {x, y} ∈ ln3, {x, y}][[1, All, 2]];
    i2 = Solve[{x, y} ∈ ln1 && {x, y} ∈ ln3, {x, y}][[1, All, 2]];
    i3 = Solve[{x, y} ∈ ln2 && {x, y} ∈ ln3, {x, y}][[1, All, 2]];
    i4 =
      Solve[{x, y} ∈ InfiniteLine[{p[[3]], p[[4]]}] && {x, y} ∈ ln3, {x, y}][[1, All, 2]];
    Column[{
      Graphics[
        {Line[p],
         MapThread[
           Text[pts[[#1]], Offset[#2, p[[#1]]]] &,
           {Range[5], {{-8, 0}, {0, 6}, {9, 0}, {7, -7}, {-7, -8}}}],
         Text["i1", Offset[{9, 7}, i1]],
         Text["i2", Offset[{9, 7}, i2]],
         Text["i3", Offset[{-9, 7}, i3]],
         Text["i4", Offset[{-9, 7}, i4]],
         Text["d", Offset[{0, 7}, (i1 + i2)/2]],
         Text[Subscript["d", "0"], Offset[{0, 7}, (i2 + i3)/2]],
         Text["d", Offset[{0, 7}, (i3 + i4)/2]],
         Text[Subscript["d", "p"], Offset[{8, 0}, {0, p[[5, 2]] + dp[d]/2}]],
         Blue, Line[{{0, p[[5, 2]]}, {0, p[[5, 2]] + dp[d]}}], ln1, ln2, ln3,
         Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{i1, i2, i3, i4}]},
        ImageSize -> Medium],
      Spacer[{1, 20}],
      Row[{"i1 = ", i1, " i2 = ", i2, "\ni3 = ", i3, " i4 = ", i4}],
      Item[
        Row[{"d = ", d, " dp = ", dp[d], " d0 = ", EuclideanDistance[i2, i3]}],
        Alignment -> Left]},
      Center],
    {d, .45, .55, .0001, ImageSize -> 400}],
    SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: manipulate]

Comment: I appreciate you refactoring my code. It's a lot cleaner now. I thought of a solution last night.
`dx = Solve[{x, y} ∈ ln2 && {x, y} ∈ ln3 && d == 2 x, {x, y, d}]`
{{x -> 0.246765, y -> -0.339643, d -> 0.49353}}

Comment: @shirha. I found time to add dynamically positioned labels to the diagram.

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that!

Comment: @DavidC. Thanks for the invite, but I can't find the time for that these days. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternate synthetic geometry approach using [`GeometricScene`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricScene.html).

```
ri = RandomInstance[
  GeometricScene[{{o -> {0, 0}, d0, 
     p1 -> {-Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, p2, p3, p4, 
     p5, i1, i2, i3, i4, m}, {r -> 1}}, {circ = Circle[o, r], 
    EuclideanDistance[i1, i2] == EuclideanDistance[i2, i3] == 
     EuclideanDistance[i3, i4] == EuclideanDistance[i1, p5], 
    EuclideanDistance[m, p4] == EuclideanDistance[m, p5], 
    EuclideanDistance[o, p1] == EuclideanDistance[o, p3] == 
     EuclideanDistance[o, p5] == r, 
    EuclideanDistance[i2, d0] == EuclideanDistance[d0, i3], 
    GeometricAssertion[{Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]}, "Regular", 
     "Clockwise"], 
    GeometricAssertion[{i1, i2, i3, i4}, {"Inside", circ}], 
    GeometricAssertion[{i1, i2, i3, i4, d0}, "Collinear"], 
    GeometricAssertion[{p1, i1, p5}, "Collinear"], 
    GeometricAssertion[{p3, i4, p4}, "Collinear"], 
    GeometricAssertion[{p4, m, p5}, "Collinear"], 
    GeometricAssertion[{Line[{p4, p5}], Line[{i1, i4}]}, 
     "Parallel"]}], RandomSeeding -> 1]
pts = ri["Points"];
{EuclideanDistance[i1, i2], EuclideanDistance[i1, p5], 
  EuclideanDistance[i2, i3]} /. pts
```

[image: GeometricScene Solution]

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. I think it's amazing and I learned a lot from it. I hadn't studied Geometric Scene's yet. Quick question, does it generate p2-p5 given `o` and `p1` and `GeometricAssertion[{Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]}, "Regular", "Clockwise"]`?

Comment: @shirha You are welcome.  If you do not specify p1, it gives you a randomly oriented pentagram.  If you don't specify Clockwise, it may reverse the direction of the ordering of the vertices on the pentagram.  It was purely to get the visualization consistent with your figure.  I find `GeometricScene` to be interesting, underused, but sometimes tricky to get the hang of.